# How to target specific Cucumber runner classes or feature files within Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to target specific runner classes or feature files within Jenkins?

Let's say for example I have the following files.

Runner classes:

```
RunnerClass1.java
RunnerClass1.java
```

Feature Files:

```
Login.feature
SignUp.feature
```

Is there a way to trigger specific runner classes or feature files within the Jenkins UI, I know you can use specific plugins such as: 'Parameterised / String Parameters', has anyone else found a solution to target specific tests from Jenkins?

thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, this is possible if your scenarios are tagged https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#running-a-subset-of-scenarios

Comment: You can use `Maven` with `surefire-plugin` to run specific `Runner` classes. The runners will be responsible for running specific tests. I can guide you if you want this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag your test cases and maven will be able to run them by these tags.

For example, When I have Login cases with `@Login` tags and I want to run them with `Maven`, I am using the following terminal script :

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Login"
```